# How to implement the behaviour of -time-passes in my own Jitter?

Tags: performance, llvm, jit

I am working on a Jitter which is based on LLVM. I have a real issue with performance. I was reading a lot about this and I know it is a problem in LLVM. However, I am wondering if there are other bottlenecks. Hence, I want to use in my Jitter the same mechanism offers by -time-passes, but saving the result to a specific file. In this way, I can do some simple math like:

real_execution_time = total_time - time_passes

I added the option to the command line, but it does not work:

```
// Disable branch fold for accurate line numbers.
llvm_argv[arrayIndex++] = "-disable-branch-fold";
llvm_argv[arrayIndex++] = "-stats";
llvm_argv[arrayIndex++] = "-time-passes";
llvm_argv[arrayIndex++] = "-info-output-file"; 
llvm_argv[arrayIndex++] = "pepe.txt";

cl::ParseCommandLineOptions(arrayIndex, const_cast<char**>(llvm_argv));
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution. I am publishing the solution because It may be useful for someone else.

Before any exit(code) in your program you must include a call to

llvm::llvm_shutdown();

This call flush the information to the file.

My problem was:

1 - Other threads emitted exit without the mentioned call.

2 - There is a fancy struct llvm::llvm_shutdown_obj with a destructor which call to the mentioned method. I had declared a variable in the main function as follow:

```
llvm::llvm_shutdown_obj X();
```

Everybody know that the compiler should call the destructor, but in this case it was no happening. The reason is that the variable was not used, so the compiler removed it. 
No variable => No destructor => No flush to the file